Two Id two name join in one table to another table
I have two tables
Customer - Cid and Sid same values:



Cid
name
SID




1
Aman
1


2
Cash
2



And transtion:



TID.
Cid
debit
Credit
SID




A1
1
400
0.00
2


A2
2
0.00
400
1



I want output like this in SQL



Name.
Debit
credit
sid name




Aman
400
0.00
Cash


Cash
0.00
400
Aman



With an inner join query.

thistable.Cid   and thattable.Cid you also may want to lookup the "union all" operator.

what dbms youre using?

you could use simple JOIN eg.
SELECT C.name,T.debit,T.Credit, (select name from Customer where Cid = T.SID) [sid name] FROM Customer C LEFT JOIN Transtion T ON C.Cid = T.Cid
https://dbfiddle.uk/iXmgKxK0

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Since you want to use INNER JOIN according to your question, you can just join the table transtion twice with the table customer, once with column cid, once with column sid:
SELECT
  c1.name,
  t.debit,
  t.credit,
  c2.name AS "sid name"
FROM
  transtion t
  INNER JOIN customer c1
    ON c1.cid = t.cid
  INNER JOIN customer c2
    ON c2.sid = t.sid
ORDER BY
  c1.name;

See this sample fiddle
